# What is a good yui replacement for jquery.live

Tags: javascript, jquery, yui

jQuery.live

Added in jQuery 1.3: Binds a handler to an event (like click) for all current - and future - matched element. Can also bind custom events.

http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live

Is there a good YUI replacement which can do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In YUI3, [delegates](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/event/#delegate) perform this function. The following snippet will fire a method called "clickHandler" on any 'p' tag in the body.

```
YUI().use('event', function(Y) {
  Y.delegate("click", clickHandler, "body", "p");
});
```

YUI 2.8.0 has [delegate](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/event/#delegate) functionality as well, but the syntax is slightly different.

Comment: From the docs it looks like unlike jQuery 1.3.2, YUI lets you specify which element in the DOM you want to bind the event delegation to (3rd parameter in your example). Sweet! The selector is the last parameter.

Comment: There are a few options. Each YUI3 Node element provides a 'delegate' function, which eliminates the third argument in the example I show above, but the example I show above doesn't require you to instantiate a Node first, which I find convenient sometimes.