# Removing DOM event handlers in long-running browser session

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, xmlhttprequest, dom-events

I have a browser interface with a **ul#contacts** list on the left and **div#contact** property panel (email, phone) on the right. Click a contact in the list and my app makes an XHR request to get the contact property HTML fragment and update div#contact.innerHTML.

Each contact fragment has an "Edit Contact" link.  With JS, I progressively upgrade that link with an event listener that performs an XHR request to replace the static property panel with an in-place edit form.  This can happen many times during a single browser session.

How should I clean up my "Edit Contact" event listener?  Do I need to remove it manually before the form overwrites the property panel?  Or is the event listener cleaned up automatically when the contents of div#contact (and the node that I'm listening on) is overwritten?

FWIW, I still consider IE6 to be part of my target market.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to detach your listeners first, yes. However, the simplest thing is to not attach to the link directly, instead using [event delegation](http://www.sitepoint.com/blogs/2008/07/23/javascript-event-delegation-is-easier-than-you-think/). If you're using jQuery, it's made even simpler via the [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) method.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm using YUI3, but they have a similar delegate method.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1668804/what-is-a-good-yui-replacement-for-jquery-live